# I'm getting errors linked to 'bundle.js' and not with Original.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with why my errors are not linked to the exact React.js files like App.js. I am creating my React app using 'create-react-app' but my errors are linked to 'bundle.js' file. Why this is happening?

I'm using 'create-react-app' and this is something that already coms with 'source-map' but I don't know why it is not working. I even tried out 'webpack.config.js' but nothing happenend.

Comment: create-react-app is dead. It has even been removed from the list of recommendations of React docs. You should consider using Vite instead. The setup is easy and it’s also a lot more efficient. CRA doesn’t go through routine updates anymore so errors and warnings will keep increasing as days pass.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.